# gmaps4rails -- how to check value of process_geocoding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I'm using gmaps4rails and want to check the current value of "process_geocoding" (i.e., check if it is true or false).

The reason for this is I want to add a crude "rate limiter" (sleep 0.25) when saving a lot of records at once (so that I don't get over_quota errors from Google), but I only want to do this if process_geocoding is currently set to true (and !gmaps, but that part is easy).

I assume this is super simple, but for the life of me can't figure this out.

I tried the obvious:

```
if Building.acts_as_gmappable :process_geocoding
  do stuff
end
```

But that didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A little more details on this .... I explicitly set process_geocoding to false when I do an import. This prevents geocoding hundreds or thousands of records at once. Then I explicitly set process_geocoding back to false when the import is done. I realize I could use my own variable and set that to true or false at the same time as I set process_geocoding . . . but that seems silly.

Comment: I meant "Then I explicity set process_geocoding back to true when the import is done".

Comment: As a temporary workaround I've done the following: 1) set `IS_GEOCODING = true` in config/application.rb, 2) `AppName::Application.const_set(:IS_GEOCODING, false)` at the same time I set process_geocoding to false, 3) `AppName::Application.const_set(:IS_GEOCODING, true)` when I'm done importing, and 4) check `if !gmaps && AppName::Application::IS_GEOCODING` before I do  `sleep 0.25`. Not elegant (or thread safe, which isn't a big deal because I only do imports off-hours) but it works for now. Would love to know how to check the state of process_geocoding instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of this gem answered my question over on github:

https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/issues/374

The correct way to do this is to check gmaps4rails_options on the instance not on the Class, i.e.:

```
your_object.gmaps4rails_options[:process_geocoding]
```

So in my case:

```
building.gmaps4rails_options[:process_geocoding]
```

Since the setting is "global", I don't believe it matters which instance you check. Not sure why I can't just call this as a class method, but this works regardless.